# How can I get the value of a stdClass?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Here is the result of this:

```
dd(DB::select('select FOUND_ROWS()')[0]);

/*
{#257 ▼
  +"FOUND_ROWS()": 8
}
```

How can I get `8`?

**Note1:** `DB::select('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')[0]->FOUND_ROWS()` won't work.

**Note2:** I cannot set any alias for it in the query like `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * AS num ...`

**Note3:** This won't work either `DB::select('select FOUND_ROWS()')[0]->toArray()`

**Note4:** And this one either `DB::select('select FOUND_ROWS()')[0]->get()`

Comment: `dd(DB::select('select FOUND_ROWS()')->get());` ?

Comment: @Hussein `"Call to undefined method stdClass::get()`

Comment: why don't you use the model to access the collection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing not standard property names is done with `{}`:

```
dd(DB::select('select FOUND_ROWS()')[0]->{'FOUND_ROWS()'});
```